# Drupal user access callback selective response

Tags: drupal, access-denied, user-permissions

Please bear with this Drupal API novice whilst I explain some background stuff!

I have been experimenting with the code below to create 2 separate responses when my users click on a custom node creation link. By default, a page opens that allows users to go through the usual steps in creating a node.
What my module does is check if the user has specific permissions and either allow them to proceed in creating the node or throw up an access denied page.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {  
  $items["node/add/page/%"]['access callback'] = 'mymodule_access_callback';
}

function mymodule_access_callback(){
  if( user_access('open sesame') ){
    drupal_set_message("successfully intecepting new node creation");
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The node/add/page is blocked successfully but it does so in both cases. The if statement determines if the user has a certain permission and within it I added return true which resulted in the following error:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required '/node.pages.inc' (include_path='.:') in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/includes/menu.inc on line 347

As a novice, I am not sure what I need to do in order to avoid the access denied page for the right users.

Comment: To notice that Drupal doesn't define any menu callback for "node/add/page/%"; you are altering a menu item that doesn't exist, and you should not use `hook_menu_alter()` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {  
  $items["node/add/page/%"]['access callback'] = 'mymodule_access_callback';
  $items["node/add/page/%"]['file'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'node') . '/node.pages.inc';
}
```

**EDIT**

Try changing the second line above to this:

```
$items["node/add/page"]['file'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'node') . '/node.pages.inc';
```

It's an attempt to explicitly set the file path for the parent item of the path you're defining.

Also this might be a stupid thing to say but every time you make a change to `hook_menu_alter()` make sure you clear Drupal's caches so the changes are picked up.

Comment: Sorry, it's made no difference

Comment: At second glance the reason is because there is no `node/add/page/%` path set in `node.module` (see [`node_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_menu/6)) so you're not actually altering anything, just adding a new menu item without a `page callback` which is why you get the error.

Comment: You could be right but in the case of a menu missing a callback, it should revert to the nearest parent's callback function, shouldn't it. Atleast that's what I read at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/group/menu/6

Comment: Yes you're right, putting that together with the error message you're getting led me to think that the `file` path was being set incorrectly (relative to the node module, not the root) hence the answer above :/ The only thing I can think to try is to explicitly set the path for the parent item. I'll edit the answer above to show you what I mean

Comment: Thanks for the answer and code from your last update. I was able to try your suggestion to day but it has made no difference. I get an error similar to my original post above. I simply don't know enough about the API to figure this out :-(

Comment: Studying the error closely, I realized the problem is a malformed URL to the node.pages.inc. It's trying to find it at 'modules/node/modules/node/modules/node.pages.inc'